# target pseudo selectors in material ui

Tags: css-selectors, material-ui

I'm wondering if there's a way to target psedo selectors (`::before, ::after`) in material ui?
For example, in a component like this?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    '&::before': {
      content: '"blabla"'
    },
    '&::after': {
      content: '"blabla"'
    },
    ':before': {},
    after: {}
  }
}));

function App(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Typography
      className={{ root: classes.root, before: classes.before, after: classes.after }}>
      {props.children}
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this `className={{ root: classes.root}}` only?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Yes. Eg, I want to add dashes before and after the element. I add `'&::before': {
      content: '""',
      display: 'block',
      border: '1px solid gray',
      width: '75%',
      margin: '20px auto'
    }` but they do not appear

Comment: I have created this [sandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-heisenberg-ddbr6?file=/src/component.js), you can check,  things are working fine or correct me if I am missing something

Comment: yeah, I was totally messing with classNames. what also worked for me is this syntax `'&:before'`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created [this sandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-heisenberg-ddbr6?file=/src/component.js:0-485), you can check, things are working fine or correct me if I am missing something to understand your problem

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    textAlign: "center",
    "&::before": {
      content: '"-"'
    },
    "&::after": {
      content: '"-"'
    }
  }
}));

export default function App(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Typography className={classes.root} {...props}>
      Hello
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

I think you are using the `className` props in a wrong way, you have to pass the string, not an object.
`classes` props expect an object, we generally use classes props on the component which have exposed class names to override their inner styles, for example in case of [Typography](https://material-ui.com/api/typography/) Component you can override root element style like this.

```
export default function App(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Typography classes={{ root: classes.root }} {...props}>
      Hello
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

so `classes` and `classNames` are two different things in Material-UI, but sometimes(when you want to apply the style to root element of component) both provide the same solution.

I have created one more [Sandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-davinci-qn62k?file=/src/component.js:316-492) with the second solution